# Testar função de soma

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá pessoal tudo bem? primeiramente quero dizer que é um prazer fazer parte desta comunidade.
Estou estudando python por conta própria, achei um curso por aplicativo, já estou na parte de funções mas não compreendi corretamente a sintaxe do comando.
Eu gostaria de fazer algo simples, implementar uma função de soma e uma função para testar a soma, apenas para fins didáticos. 
Mas meu código não exibe nada na tela, segue:

```
def soma (x, y):
    return (x + y)

def testa_soma():
    if (soma(10, 20) == 30):
        print ('correto')
```

Answer (score 4):

Você definiu duas funções uma *testa_soma* e a *soma*, mas não fez a chamada de nenhuma delas, deveria ser assim:

```
def soma (x, y):
    return (x + y)

def testa_soma():
    if (soma(10, 20) == 30):
        print ('correto')

testa_soma()
```

Veja que na última linha eu coloquei a chamada.

Answer (score 3):

Pra que uma função seja executada, você tem que chamar ela:

```
def soma (x, y):
    return (x + y)

def testa_soma():
    if (soma(10, 20) == 30):
        print ('correto')

testa_soma()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também utilizar o modulo [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html). Com ele você pode criar os testes direto na *docstring* da função, o que centraliza os testes junto com a função e auxilia da documentação da mesma.

```
def soma(x, y):
    """ Retorna a soma de dois números.

    Parâmetros:
        x, y: números a serem somados.

    Retorno:
        Resultado da soma dos números de entrada.

    Exemplos:

    >>> soma(10, 20)
    30
    >>> soma(0, 5)
    5
    >>> soma(-1, -3)
    -4
    >>> soma(-2, 3)
    1
    """
    return x + y
```

Assim, no arquivo, basta incluir:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

E quando executar o arquivo, os testes serão verificados. Se não produzir nenhuma saída, é porque todos os testes foram bem sucedidos.

Comment: e se eu quiser chamar a função testa_soma dentro da função soma? é possível? tipo pra ela já puxar o teste sozinha

Comment: @LeandroSargi isso não é bom fazer, porque quando chamar a função soma você espera que seja apenas somados os números e não testar a função; gera efeitos colaterais.

Comment: a tá ok, obrigado amigo.

Comment: Eu perguntei isso porque no meu curso, tem um exercício pra fazer um jogo. O nome é jogo do NIM, vai ser usado 6 funções, e conforme termina uma, ela passa pra outra função e executa. Não sei se perdi alguma parte da teoria, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer essa passagem